# How to use 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech' namespace with Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, text-to-speech

I'm testing the Microsoft Azure Speech services, specifically trying to use Text-To-Speech. So, I'm using a free layer of Azure, and created a TimeTrigger Azure Function to read an e-mail, traverse through HTML and then call the Speech Service with the SDK `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`. I'm using the `function.proj` to load the nuget packages, loading `S22.Imap` and `HtmlAgilityPack` without any issues. But the speech package is triggering an exception:
`Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`.
Am I able to use this package in an Azure Function? If so, what am I doing wrong?

I tried to remove the `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech" Version="1.6.0" />` line from `function.proj` and deleted `project.assets.json` to reload the package but it didn't work.

This is my `function.proj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="S22.Imap" Version="3.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech" Version="1.6.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And this is my `run.csx`:

```
using System;
using S22.Imap;
using System.Net.Mail;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    var username = "sample@gmail.com";
    var password = "sample";
    var subsKey = "sample";

    using(ImapClient client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, username, password, AuthMethod.Login, true))
    {
        IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.From("sample@sample.com"));
        IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = client.GetMessages(uids);
        log.LogInformation($"Count: {messages.Count()}.");

        var msg = messages.FirstOrDefault();
        if(msg != null)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(msg.Body);

            var paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "p" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.InnerText.Trim()))
                .ToList();

            var mailText = string.Empty;
            foreach(var par in paragraphs)
                mailText += par.InnerText;

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailText))
            {
                var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(subsKey, "myregion");
                config.SetSpeechSynthesisOutputFormat(SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat.Audio24Khz160KBitRateMonoMp3);
                config.SpeechSynthesisLanguage = "pt-BR";

                using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config))
                {
                    using (var result = synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(mailText).Result)
                    {
                        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                        {
                            //Do something with it
                        }
                        else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                        {
                            var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                            log.LogError($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                            if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                            {
                                log.LogError($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                                log.LogError($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to delete the `function.proj` then recreate one and add `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech` at first.

Make sure the `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll` has been installed in `win-x86` and `win-x64`. Please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/176).

[image]

Comment: Deleted `function.proj` and `project.assets.json`, recreated it (this time only with Cognitive Services) and it still is unable to load the DLL. Maybe I should delete the Function App and try to create it from the scratch again?

Comment: I deleted the entire function, created again, this time only the speech service, but the error keep showing up. I gave up and used the REST API, and now it works.

Comment: The rest api you use is this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech)?

Answer (score 0):

[Mark as perquisite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuWfN.png)

When you publish mark Visual c++ 14 Runtime Libraries as prerequisite

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).